# Show that $\operatorname{span}(U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_m) = U_1 + \cdots + U_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U_1, \dots , U_m$ be subspaces of $V$. Show that span($U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_m) = U_1 + \dots + U_m$

$\impliedby$ If $x \in U_1 + \dots + U_m$ then $x = u_1 + \dots + u_m$ which implies $x \in $ Span$(U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_m)$

$\implies$ If $x \in $ Span$(U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_m)$, then $x$ can be written as a linear combination of Span$(U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_m)$ as $x = u_1 + \dots + u_m$ for $u_i \in U_i$ which is equivalent to $x = u_1 + \dots + u_m$...?

I am not sure how to tie up the rest of the proof though. To me it seems like there is nothing else to conclude, but it seems incomplete.

Comment: The linear combination of span$(U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n)$ doesnt always $u_1+\cdots+u_n$. I think the more appropriate equation you want to prove is span$(U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n)$ = span $U_1+\cdots+$ span $U_n$

Answer (score 1):

The $\implies$ direction is ok, if a little terse. You should specify that $u_i \in U_i$ for each $i$, and if you want to make it even more clear, specify that the existence of these vectors comes from the definition of the sum of subspaces.

The $\impliedby$ direction is false unless the $U_i$s are subspaces, as my now deleted answer demonstrated. Notice that your argument doesn't make use of this assumption, despite its necessity, which shows that your argument needs some work.

In particular, when you assume $x \in \operatorname{span}(U_1 \cup \ldots \cup U_m)$, remember that you will not just get a sum of vectors, one from each set, but a linear combination of some number of vectors. There may be scalar multiples that are not $1$. Some of the $U_i$ sets may have multiple vectors in the linear combination, some may have none at all. How do you turn this into a sum of precisely $m$ vectors, with no scalar multiples out the front, with one vector per set?

Well, this is where the subspace condition comes in. If multiple terms of the linear combination come from a single $U_i$, group them. The combination of these terms must be an element of $U_i$, since $U_i$ is a subspace. That combination can be your vector $u_i \in U_i$, as appearing in your sum.

If some $U_i$ fails to contribute any terms to the sum, you can also use the fact that $0$ lies in every subspace, and set $u_i = 0$.

Notice how important the subspace condition is! That's primarily what is missing from your argument.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Leftarrow)$ is fine.

Whenever dealing with a finite collection of sets, it is better you prove the result for two sets and use induction.

$Claim : Span(U_1 \cup U_2) \subseteq U_1 + U_2$

$\text{To make things easy, let} \; U= U_1 \cup U_2, \;S=span(U)$

Note that:

$$x\in S \Rightarrow x= \sum_{u_i \in U}\alpha_{i} u_i =\sum_{u_i \in U\setminus U_2}\alpha_{i} u_i + \sum_{u_i\in U_2} \alpha_{i} u_i$$

Can you see where the first summand on RHS lies?